# In visual basic Compare lbl.txt and lbl.name

Tags: vb.net, string

simple question i hope.  so i need to make sure a labels.text and a labels2.name are equal.  figured it was straight forward i renamed the label the same name as the label im comparing it too but it comes up false. any help?

Answer (score 1):

Are these WebForms or WinForms labels? Substitute 'ID' below for the property you want to check.

```
Dim areSame As Boolean = (lblFirst.Text=lblSecond.ID)
```

Or you could use the .NET [`String.Compare()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx#Y979)

```
Dim areSame As Boolean = String.Compare(lblFirst.Text, lblSecond.ID)=0
```

For [case-sensitivity with String.Compare()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx):

```
Dim areSame As Boolean = String.Compare(lblFirst.Text, lblSecond.ID, False)=0
```